# C# URL Routing with variable parameters

Tags: c#, .net, routes

I have two methods in two separate controllers that I want to access, but can't seem to figure out how the custom routes should look like and if it's possible to do it without manually writing all the routes.

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
baseUrl/businessOwner/identity
```

to map to BusinessOwnerController, Identity action

```
baseUrl/{employee}/identity
```

to map to EmployeeController, Identity action

where {employee} will be a string to which I'm matching the value in the database.
Also, I want other URLs to be able to map themselves to their default behavior, such that:

```
baseUrl/accountant/identity
```

will not match on the previous routes, but will go to the default behavior: accountant - AccountantController, Identity action.

The only way for this to work (as far as I've found) was to manually map the routes in RegisterRoutes.

I've tried doing a custom route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"BusinessOwner",
"businessOwner/{action}/{id}",
new { controller = "BusinessOwner", action = "Identity", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

before the default route, but that doesn't really work out, as the "Multiple controller match" error still pops up.

I've also tried separating the controllers into different namespaces within the same Controllers folder and do the routing based on that, but still unsuccessful.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at it this way: You are using the same part of the URL to hold either an employee identifier or a string constant "BusinessOwner," which acts as a magic string to invoke the BusinessOwnerController instead of the EmployeeController.

Set up your main routes to always go to the EmployeeController, and then add in a special check in the EmployeeController which will pass control to the BusinessOwnerController if the special employee ID of "BusinessOwner" is detected.

```
class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Identity(string employeeID)
    {
        if (employeeID == "BusinessOwner")
        {
            var businessOwnerController = new BusinessOwnerController();
            businessOwnerController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(
                this.ControllerContext.RequestContext,
                businessOwnerController
            );
            return businessOwnerController.Identity();
        }
        else
        {
            //Do employee stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But this implies instantiating the BusinessOwnerController in EmployeeController, which I don't think it's a good solution.